# rake aborted! The operation: "GET MORE"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rake, moped

I am getting the below error when I run the rake task. Can any one help me?

Error

```
rake aborted!
The operation: "GET MORE"
failed with error "cursor 178700246530 not found"
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/node.rb:210:in `get_more'
```

My Rake Code

```
MyCollection.where(:name => "abc").each do |comp|   
 l =     open(comp.logo_url)
 comp.logo = l
 comp.save!
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `MyCollection` huge? That would most likely be the case. Check out the related discussion about this error at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/9QxJZg9sSZo

Comment: Yes it is huge. is there any possible way to handle this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use with [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) with your collection .

Comment: I have not used find_in_batches but code modified to use limited data at a time. It works without error. Error occur because of huge data retrieval from DB. Retrieve data partially at time and perform activity.

Comment: MyCollection.where(:name => "abc").limit(50).each do |comp|   
 l =     open(comp.logo_url)
 comp.logo = l
 comp.save!
end

Comment: #find_in_batches is not a Mopped Method. It's ActiveRecord only